# Make awk keep ending whitespace

Tags: bash, shell, awk, rsync

I have a file list with two columns. I need to remove the first column and keep a list of filenames. If I happen to have a file that ends with a space, eg "some file ", the space is removed by awk.

Example with file "input" (notice the space at the end of "some file ")

```
abc some file 
def some other file
```

Running

```
cat input | awk '{$1=""; print substr($0, 2)}' > output
```

will produce the file output

```
some file
some other file
```

where "some file " is now "some file" resulting in a non existent file when processing the file list.

Any portable solution is appreciated :)

[EDIT] Tried to simplify the example above in order to make it more clear, but in fact there are more columns so some solutions may not apply.

Actual file is an rsync --list-only output:

```
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:21 .
drwxr-xr-x      234234 2017/06/04 11:24:19 some file 
drwxr-xr-x     1341212 2017/06/04 11:24:19 some other file
```

The column that shows filesizes may expand so removing a fixed amount of trailing characters will lead to errors.

Filenames can indeed contain paths and multiple spaces.

Example test file (keep in mind that filesize may vary, so the second column might increase in size):

```
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:21 .
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:19 another
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:19 another/one
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:19 another/one/bites
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:19 another/one/bites/ de_dust
-rw-r--r--           0 2017/06/04 11:24:19 another/one/bites/ de_dust/ 2017/06/04 11:24:19 Iron Rhapsody
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:19 phantom of 
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2017/06/04 11:24:19 phantom of /the opera
-rw-r--r--           0 2017/06/04 11:24:19 phantom of /the opera/Bohemian Maiden
```

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^/]+\/.{15}/,"")}1' file
.
another
another/one
another/one/bites
another/one/bites/ de_dust
another/one/bites/ de_dust/ 2017/06/04 11:24:19 Iron Rhapsody
phantom of
phantom of /the opera
phantom of /the opera/Bohemian Maiden
```

or with GNU or OSX sed for `-E` (with strictly POSIX seds you'd escape the +, {, and }):

```
$ sed -E 's:[^/]+/.{15}::' file
.
another
another/one
another/one/bites
another/one/bites/ de_dust
another/one/bites/ de_dust/ 2017/06/04 11:24:19 Iron Rhapsody
phantom of
phantom of /the opera
phantom of /the opera/Bohemian Maiden
```

Comment: There aren't always 44 chars until the filenames because of different filesizes. Filenames may contain paths so "/" can be present in a filename. Trying to read your regex, care to explain the last one please ? Still need to adapt to fit my reqs :)

Comment: Thanks, done the editing :)
Not good at regexps, is there a way to say ```remove from the start of line to hte 17 characters after the first / on the line``` maybe ? Using a wildcard will always catch the last, and I don't know how to get the first. Thanks.

Comment: Changed your answer too fast, I just had time to improve your last one to this ```sed -E 's/^.{10} +[0-9]+ [0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} //'``` which should be some how bulletproof I guess.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks alot :)

Comment: You're welcome. Deleting my comments now to tidy up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^.* [0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} //' input
```

Output:

```
.
some file 
some other file
```

Comment: Looks great, care to explain the {10} and {8} in the regex please ?

Comment: Match exact 10 (consecutive) characters of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and /.

Comment: Thanks, just tested on Linux & BSD, seems to work great :)

Comment: @EdMorton: Okay, to fix that I suggest to use: `sed -r 's/^.{10} [0-9 ]+ [0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} //'`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `tr` and `cut` :

```
 tr -s ' ' <inputfile | cut -d' ' -f5-
```

Comment: Could work only as long as there is no filename with more than one consecutive space

Comment: @deajan It would also strip off a leading space but that wasn't stated in your requirement.